# A code to imput missing values with linear dependency

Tags: r, tidyverse, radix

I've got a data.frame with weekly data as below:

```
structure(list(date = structure(1:9, .Label = c("2017-01-01", 
"2017-01-08", "2017-01-15", "2017-01-22", "2017-01-29", "2017-02-05", 
"2017-02-12", "2017-02-19", "2017-02-26"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c("6", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "6", "8", "10")), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now I want to calculate daily data with smoothing that changes the values from day to day linearly with an amount of change equal to one seventh of weekly change. So the expected output would be:

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(17167, 17168, 17169, 17170, 
17171, 17172, 17173, 17174, 17175, 17176, 17177, 17178, 17179, 
17180, 17181, 17182, 17183, 17184, 17185, 17186, 17187, 17188, 
17189, 17190, 17191, 17192, 17193, 17194, 17195, 17196, 17197, 
17198, 17199, 17200, 17201, 17202, 17203, 17204, 17205, 17206, 
17207, 17208, 17209, 17210, 17211, 17212, 17213, 17214, 17215, 
17216, 17217, 17218, 17219, 17220, 17221, 17222, 17223, 17224, 
17225), class = "Date"), value = c(6, 5.857, 5.714, 5.571, 5.429, 
5.286, 5.143, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5.143, 5.286, 5.429, 5.571, 
5.714, 5.857, 6, 6.286, 6.571, 6.857, 7.143, 7.429, 7.714, 8, 
8.286, 8.571, 8.857, 9.143, 9.429, 9.714, 10, 8.57, 7.14)), row.names = c(NA, 
-59L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Please note that last two dates are not within time span from first data frame and they decrease by (10 - 0) / 7 as the difference is calculated from last observed value (10) to 0.

How can I obtain expected output?

Comment: could you make your example data copy&pastable?

Comment: I edited the post with `dput` output

Comment: how is the calculation done? How do we get 5.86 and 5.71 as 2nd and 3rd value?

Comment: The difference between last observed weekly value (6) and next observed weekly value (5) is calculated, divided by 7 and following values are decreased by it subsequentially. So 5.86 is 6 - 1/7, 5.71 is 5.86 - 1.7 and so on.

Answer (score 2):

does this help?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attache Paket: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date
library(padr)

mydf<- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
          index = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
          date = c("01.01.2017", "08.01.2017", "15.01.2017", "22.01.2017",
                 "29.01.2017", "05.02.2017", "12.02.2017", "19.02.2017",
                 "26.02.2017"),
          value = c(6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 8, 10)
)


mydf %>% 
  mutate(date=lubridate::dmy(date)) %>% 
  pad(.,interval="day", end_val=lubridate::dmy("28.02.2017")) %>% 
  mutate(value2=approx(date,value,date)$y)
#>    index       date value    value2
#> 1      1 2017-01-01     6  6.000000
#> 2     NA 2017-01-02    NA  5.857143
#> 3     NA 2017-01-03    NA  5.714286
#> 4     NA 2017-01-04    NA  5.571429
#> 5     NA 2017-01-05    NA  5.428571
#> 6     NA 2017-01-06    NA  5.285714
#> 7     NA 2017-01-07    NA  5.142857
#> 8      2 2017-01-08     5  5.000000
#> 9     NA 2017-01-09    NA  5.000000
#> 10    NA 2017-01-10    NA  5.000000
#> 11    NA 2017-01-11    NA  5.000000
#> 12    NA 2017-01-12    NA  5.000000
#> 13    NA 2017-01-13    NA  5.000000
#> 14    NA 2017-01-14    NA  5.000000
#> 15     3 2017-01-15     5  5.000000
#> 16    NA 2017-01-16    NA  5.000000
#> 17    NA 2017-01-17    NA  5.000000
#> 18    NA 2017-01-18    NA  5.000000
#> 19    NA 2017-01-19    NA  5.000000
#> 20    NA 2017-01-20    NA  5.000000
#> 21    NA 2017-01-21    NA  5.000000
#> 22     4 2017-01-22     5  5.000000
#> 23    NA 2017-01-23    NA  5.000000
#> 24    NA 2017-01-24    NA  5.000000
#> 25    NA 2017-01-25    NA  5.000000
#> 26    NA 2017-01-26    NA  5.000000
#> 27    NA 2017-01-27    NA  5.000000
#> 28    NA 2017-01-28    NA  5.000000
#> 29     5 2017-01-29     5  5.000000
#> 30    NA 2017-01-30    NA  5.000000
#> 31    NA 2017-01-31    NA  5.000000
#> 32    NA 2017-02-01    NA  5.000000
#> 33    NA 2017-02-02    NA  5.000000
#> 34    NA 2017-02-03    NA  5.000000
#> 35    NA 2017-02-04    NA  5.000000
#> 36     6 2017-02-05     5  5.000000
#> 37    NA 2017-02-06    NA  5.142857
#> 38    NA 2017-02-07    NA  5.285714
#> 39    NA 2017-02-08    NA  5.428571
#> 40    NA 2017-02-09    NA  5.571429
#> 41    NA 2017-02-10    NA  5.714286
#> 42    NA 2017-02-11    NA  5.857143
#> 43     7 2017-02-12     6  6.000000
#> 44    NA 2017-02-13    NA  6.285714
#> 45    NA 2017-02-14    NA  6.571429
#> 46    NA 2017-02-15    NA  6.857143
#> 47    NA 2017-02-16    NA  7.142857
#> 48    NA 2017-02-17    NA  7.428571
#> 49    NA 2017-02-18    NA  7.714286
#> 50     8 2017-02-19     8  8.000000
#> 51    NA 2017-02-20    NA  8.285714
#> 52    NA 2017-02-21    NA  8.571429
#> 53    NA 2017-02-22    NA  8.857143
#> 54    NA 2017-02-23    NA  9.142857
#> 55    NA 2017-02-24    NA  9.428571
#> 56    NA 2017-02-25    NA  9.714286
#> 57     9 2017-02-26    10 10.000000
```

edited version to include jakes comment:

```
mydf <- mydf %>% 
  mutate(date=lubridate::dmy(date))

end_row <- tibble(date=max(mydf$date)+7,value=0)

bind_rows(mydf, end_row) %>% 
  pad(.,interval="day") %>%  
  mutate(value2=approx(date,value,date)$y) %>% 
  filter(date<dmy("28.02.2017")+1)
```

Comment: it does. but what about last two values? (my expected output df has 59 rows)

Comment: I added end_val=lubridate::dmy("28.02.2017")) to the pad command; howevere, there is no interpolation to the value 0 since the last value is NA and not 0. For that I think the original values would have to be changed, i.e. append an entry with the value 0 to the end.

Comment: I added a revised version to include 0 value